# How to combine decoded packet data and header output into a single variable/dictionary for string searches

Tags: python, variables, packet

I'm somewhat of a Python novice, but I've taken up a small personal project to teach myself a bit more. Basically, I'm writing a packet sniffer using sockets and impacket. However, where I am getting stuck at is one particular point: combining the output from header and packet into one variable (I was thinking of a dictionary, but it didn't like that...) so that I can simply search out the IP header for one particular partial source IP (i.e., the first two octets). Or would there be a more efficient way of handling this? Any help is appreciated. :-)

EDIT: When I was trying the dictionary, I was doing

```
ip_dict = { header: packet }
```

However, the output I get is akin to this:

```
{<impacket.ImpactPacket.IP instance at 0x02563440>: <impacket.ImpactPacket.Data instance at 0x02563530>}
```

As opposed to the actual output of said IP header and data.

```
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 0))

while True:

    # Include IP headers
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

    # receive all packages
    s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

    # receive a packet
    packet = s.recvfrom(42028)[0]

    # look at IP info
    h_decode = ImpactDecoder.IPDecoder()
    header = h_decode.decode(packet)

    # disabled promiscuous mode
    s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)

    decoder = ImpactDecoder.DataDecoder()
    packet = decoder.decode(packet)

    print header
    print packet

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What does "(I was thinking of a dictionary, but it didn't like that...)" mean?  You should be able to build a dictionary with the header and the packet as values if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are sets of key/value pairs.  When you used

```
ip_dict = { header: packet }
```

You told it to build a dictionary with the header instance as the key and the packet instance as the value, which is what it did:

```
{<impacket.ImpactPacket.IP instance at 0x02563440>: <impacket.ImpactPacket.Data instance at 0x02563530>}
```

If you want something from inside those instances, you have to extract it yourself.  For example, although I've never used the `impacket` library before, the objects seem to have lots of methods living inside them.  For example [suppressing the real numbers and data and replacing them with nonsense]:

```
In [25]: z
Out[25]: <impacket.ImpactPacket.IP instance at 0xb6151fac>

In [26]: z.[here I hit TAB in the IPython interpreter]
z.add_option              z.get_ip_offmask          z.set_bytes_from_string
z.auto_checksum           z.get_ip_p                z.set_checksum_from_data
z.calculate_checksum      z.get_ip_rf               z.set_ip_address
z.child                   z.get_ip_src              z.set_ip_df
z.compute_checksum        z.get_ip_sum              z.set_ip_dst
z.contains                z.get_ip_tos              z.set_ip_hl
z.ethertype               z.get_ip_ttl              z.set_ip_id
z.fragment_by_list        z.get_ip_v                z.set_ip_len
z.fragment_by_size        z.get_long                z.set_ip_mf
z.get_buffer_as_string    z.get_packet              z.set_ip_off
z.get_byte                z.get_pseudo_header       z.set_ip_offmask
z.get_bytes               z.get_size                z.set_ip_p
z.get_data_as_string      z.get_word                z.set_ip_rf
z.get_header_size         z.is_BSD                  z.set_ip_src
z.get_ip_address          z.list_as_hex             z.set_ip_sum
z.get_ip_df               z.load_header             z.set_ip_tos
z.get_ip_dst              z.normalize_checksum      z.set_ip_ttl
z.get_ip_hl               z.packet_printable        z.set_ip_v
z.get_ip_id               z.parent                  z.set_long
z.get_ip_len              z.protocol                z.set_parent
z.get_ip_mf               z.set_byte                z.set_word
z.get_ip_off              z.set_bytes               

In [26]: z.get_ip_src()
Out[26]: '1.2.3.4' # fake

In [27]: z.get_ip_dst()
Out[27]: '5.6.7.8' # fake

In [29]: z.get_data_as_string()
Out[29]: '\x00abcde' # fake
```

I have no idea what half of the methods do, or which of them are important, but you can easily build a dictionary out of whatever you like:

```
In [31]: {(z.get_ip_src(), z.get_ip_dst()): z.get_bytes()}
Out[31]: 
{('1.2.3.4',
  '5.6.7.8'): array('B', [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])} # fake
```

or combine bits from the IPDecoder and the DataDecoder, whatever.  The point is that the issue isn't about Python dictionaries, it's about the `impacket` library's data structures, and what information you want to extract from them.  The docs will probably describe how to get what you need.